# How to Create a PagedList from a VarChar(MAX) field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a database table with a VARCHAR(MAX) field and I would like to be able to paginate that data in an MVC view using a PagedList, I would like paginate at x chars. I am guessing that it is not going to be pretty to do this. My model returns MasterId int, contentData VarChar(MAX), and some other fields. 
I would like to know how I can transform the varchar(max) field into several pages (there is a page Break symbol in the data).

I am thinking since my model only contains a contentData that trying to use PagedList might not work .

Should I even attempt this?
Should I simply bite the bullet and just redesign the database table and then the associated CRUD code ?

I am thinking I will probably end up doing the latter option - unless someone points me into a nice way to do it as it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't paginate it, but do something to show partial data and update the view instead.

You haven't said *Why* so I'll make the assumption to not send more data than is useful to the user most of the time.

Assumptions: A class Something like:

```
public class ContentView 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Content {get; set; }
   public DateTime LastEditedTime { get; set; }
}
```

You could query (psuedo code at my whim):

```
 dbContext.Books.Join(EditHistory, b => b.Id, e => e.BookId, (b,e) => new {b, e})
   .Select(new ContentView() {Id = b.Id, 
   content = b.Exceprt.Substring(0, Math.Min(b.Exceprt.Length, 100)),
   LastEditedTime = e.ModifiedTime}).ToList();
```

So the string would be 100 characters here.

Then in the view have a method called via a button (a magnifying glass, or ellipses for example) that calls the API / database with the ID and returns the full text.

If you had to paginate it:

Replace `string content` with a class similar to:

```
public class Content 
{
   public int Page { get; set; }
   public string BookText { get; set; }
}
```

and then each time you clicked the button the query could fetch either more data and append:

```
return db.Books.Where(w => w.Id == id)
.Select(s => new Content() {
   BookText = s.Passage.substring(page * 100, page + 1 * 100),
   Page = page++ );
```

or a similar substring from 0 to current page number * number characters per page and replace the existing content.